# Error on & with attribute selector in SCSS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins, scss-lint

> **SCSS code:** .parent-class {    &[dir='rtl'] {
> &__cta {
> p {
> margin-left: 6px;
> margin-right: initial;
> }
> }  }
> }
>
> **Error:**  sass error Invalid parent selector "[dir=rtl]"
>
> &[dir='rtl'] {   &__cta {
> p {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gives you a hint:

```
.parent-class {
    &[dir='rtl'] {
        &__cta {
            p {
                margin-left: 6px;
                margin-right: initial;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This selector is **invalid** because it would compile to:
`.parent-class[dir='rtl']__cta`

Depending on your markup, you might want to write it like that:

```
 .parent-class {
     $root: &;
     
     &[dir='rtl'] { 
         & #{$root}__cta { 
             p { 
                 margin-left: 6px; 
                 margin-right: initial; 
             } 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

That would compile to:
`.parent-class[dir=rtl] .parent-class__cta p`